# How to use recursive method to update python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am working with Python zeep to make SOAP requests. As far as I know zeep can make requests with dictionaries as inputs.

Since I am working with multiple methods, I want to make a generic function to receive parameters with their corresponding hierarchy defined in the method's WSDL and construct the request_data_dictionary that could be very complex taking into account that it can have nested data.

When defining my parameters I gave them a level attribute to know how deep in the request data dictionary the parameter should be. And I am certain that the parameters are processed in order.

My test case has the following structure. I have 4 parameters: par1, par2, par3 and par4. Each parameter is child of the parameter with a lower numbering, so par2 is child of par1 and so on. The data output I need has the following form:

{'par0': {'par1': {'par2': {'par3': {'par4': False}}}}}

If I add a par2.1 as another child of par1 the dictionary should have this form:

{'par0': {'par1': {'par2.1': False, 'par2': {'par3': {'par4': False}}}}}

So I coded the following function to construct my request_dictionary:

```py
    def _prepare_request_dictionary(self):
        data_dictionary = {}
        for line in self.request_line_ids.sorted(key=lambda l: l.parameter_id.level):
            parameter_name = line.parameter_id.name
            parent_parameter_name = line.parameter_id.parent_id.name if line.parameter_id.parent_id else False
            line_value = convert_value(line.value, line.parameter_type) if not line.parameter_id.is_compound and line.value else False
            if line.parameter_id.level == 1 and parameter_name not in data_dictionary.keys():
                data_dictionary[parameter_name] = line_value
            elif line.parameter_id.level == 2:
                if parent_parameter_name in data_dictionary.keys():
                    data_dictionary = if isinstance(data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name], dict):
                        data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name] = {**data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name], **{parameter_name: line_value}}
                    elif isinstance(data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name], list):
                        data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name].append({parameter_name: line_value})
                    elif data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name] is False:
                        data_dictionary[parent_parameter_name] = {parameter_name: line_value}
            elif line.parameter_id.level == 3:
                for value in data_dictionary.values():
                    if isinstance(value, dict):
                        if parent_parameter_name in value.keys():
                            if isinstance(value[parent_parameter_name], dict):
                                value[parent_parameter_name] = {**value[parent_parameter_name], **{parameter_name: line_value}}
                            elif isinstance(value[parent_parameter_name], list):
                                value[parent_parameter_name].append({parameter_name: line_value})
                            elif value[parent_parameter_name] is False:
                                value[parent_parameter_name] = {parameter_name: line_value}
            elif line.parameter_id.level == 4:
                for value in data_dictionary.values():
                    if isinstance(value, dict):
                        for sub_value in value.values():
                            if parent_parameter_name in sub_value.keys():
                                if isinstance(sub_value[parent_parameter_name], dict):
                                    sub_value[parent_parameter_name] = {**sub_value[parent_parameter_name], **{parameter_name: line_value}}
                                elif isinstance(sub_value[parent_parameter_name], list):
                                    sub_value[parent_parameter_name].append({parameter_name: line_value})
                                elif sub_value[parent_parameter_name] is False:
                                    sub_value[parent_parameter_name] = {parameter_name: line_value}
            elif line.parameter_id.level == 5:
                for value in data_dictionary.values():
                    if isinstance(value, dict):
                        for sub_value in value.values():
                            if isinstance(sub_value, dict):
                                for sub_sub_value in sub_value.values():
                                    if isinstance(sub_sub_value, dict):
                                        if parent_parameter_name in sub_sub_value.keys():
                                            if isinstance(sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name], dict):
                                                sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name] = {**sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name], **{parameter_name: line_value}}
                                            elif isinstance(sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name], list):
                                                sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name].append({parameter_name: line_value})
                                            elif sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name] is False:
                                                sub_sub_value[parent_parameter_name] = {parameter_name: line_value}
        return data_dictionary
```

As you can see this function has some repetitive parts, like the following one:

```py
if isinstance(value[parent_parameter_name], dict):
                                value[parent_parameter_name] = {**value[parent_parameter_name], **{parameter_name: line_value}}
elif isinstance(value[parent_parameter_name], list):
                                value[parent_parameter_name].append({parameter_name: line_value})
elif value[parent_parameter_name] is False:
                                value[parent_parameter_name] = {parameter_name: line_value}
```

And this other one:

```py
for value in data_dictionary.values():
   if isinstance(value, dict):
      for sub_value in value.values():
         if isinstance(sub_value, dict):
            for sub_sub_value in sub_value.values():
               if isinstance(sub_sub_value, dict):
```

So I made a subfunction called "update_data_dictionary" to modularize it:

```py
def update_data_dictionary(work_dictionary, update_dictionary, parent_parameter):
    if isinstance(work_dictionary[parent_parameter], dict):
        work_dictionary[parent_parameter] = {**work_dictionary[parent_parameter], **update_dictionary}
    elif isinstance(work_dictionary[parent_parameter], list):
        work_dictionary[parent_parameter].append(update_dictionary)
    elif work_dictionary[parent_parameter] is False:
        work_dictionary[parent_parameter] = update_dictionary
    return work_dictionary
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use this method again further level 3, because the function "update_data_dictionary" returns a dictionary that can't replace the value.

I know that this could be solved with recursive functions, if someone could help me making this a recursive function working with infinite levels I will be so grateful.

Comment: Can you give an example of data and an example of resulting dictionary with desirable structure you want to build? At this moment it's hard to understand that your code does and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I edited to explain better how the dictionaries I want should output.
Something I didn't mention is that I am working with Odoo and the request_line_ids variable is a recordset of a model I have created the same with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while but I was able to create the recursive method I needed, it has the following form:

```py
def update_data_dictionary(work_dictionary, line_value, parameter, work_level=0, sub_dictionary=None):
    parameter_name = parameter.name
    parent_parameter = parameter.parent_id.name
    parent_level = parameter.parent_id.level
    level = 1 if work_level == 0 else work_level
    update_dictionary = sub_dictionary if sub_dictionary else {parameter_name: line_value}
    if parent_level == level:
        if parent_parameter in work_dictionary.keys():
            if isinstance(work_dictionary[parent_parameter], dict):
                work_dictionary[parent_parameter] = {**work_dictionary[parent_parameter], **update_dictionary}
            elif work_dictionary[parent_parameter] is False:
                work_dictionary[parent_parameter] = update_dictionary
    else:
        for value in work_dictionary.copy().values():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                processed_dictionary = update_data_dictionary(value, line_value, parameter, (level+1), update_dictionary)
    return work_dictionary
```

This method updates the content of any child parameter in any level, as long as the level of the parameter and it's parenting hierarchy is well defined.